# Is there any way to construct DOM in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to construct DOM from the scratch in Firefox Addon SDK?

I know that there's such thing like [nsIDOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMParser) but I don't see anything like `nsIDOMConstructor` or something like this and I don't want to just concatenate strings like this

```
const html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body><a href="' + href + '">Link</a></body></html>';
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the domparser to create an empty document and then use regular DOM APIs to populate it.